# Theme Options page not saving data correctly

Tags: theme-options

I am struggling to save the correct data in my themes options page.  Here is my code in my functions.php file:

```
<?php 
if ( get_option( 'everes_options' ) ) { 
    $everes_options = get_option( 'everes_options' ); }
else {
    add_option( 'everes_options', array(
        'everes_pdf' => '1', 
        'everes_showBlog' => '1'
    ) );
    $everes_options = get_option( 'everes_options' ); }
}

function everes_options(){
    global $everes_options;
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>Resume Options</h2>
      <form action="edit.php?post_type=employment&page=resume_options" method="post">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Print as PDF?</td>
            <td>
              <select name="everes_pdf">
                <option value="1" <?php selected( '1', $everes_options['everes_pdf'] ); ?> >Yes</option>
                <option value="0" <?php selected( '0', $everes_options['everes_pdf'] ); ?> >No</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Show blog</td>
            <td>
              <select name="everes_showBlog">
                <option value="1" <?php selected( '1', $everes_options['everes_showBlog'] ); ?> >Yes</option>
                <option value="0" <?php selected( '0', $everes_options['everes_showBlog'] ); ?> >No</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php submit_button(); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

When I submit the data, it will save the data, but after a few clicks in the menu, or refreshed in the website, the data disappears.  I can't see where the issue is, but I do believe that it would be glaringly obvious to someone here.  Any help?  Please?

Comment: Your code is quite bad, why the action of the options form is `edit.php`? Anyway, you should use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to build a theme or plugin options page.

Comment: It might be duplicating things, but this is for a resume theme.  I have a set of options specifically for the resume and one specifically for the theme.  I guess, since they are both small, I should really combine them.

Comment: However, I have followed a video tutorial for this, which can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAkdS3qMCzs (Apologies if this violates any rules, I did get into trouble for posting an external link before).  I've probably royally screwed it up, but that's what I do best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution that I was (sort of) looking for. I searched for a video tutorial to integrate my settings with the Theme Customization page, which does pretty much what I wanted it to, and I think might actually be more beneficial there.